# Getting "Invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)" when requiring file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sass, rubygems

This question has been added already, but my case seems a little different.

**Machine:** Windows Server 2012
**Ruby:** Version 1.9.3 p484

I have my main ruby file `file1.rb`:

```
module Sass::Script::Functions
  def dosome()
    # Doing some stuff
    begin
      success = require_relative 'myfile2.rb'
    rescue Exception => e
      puts "Error: #{e.message} - #{e.backtrace}!"
    end
  end
end
```

This is my `file2.rb`:

```
my_var = 'Hello world!'
```

I get this error:

> C:/myproject/file2.rb:1: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
>   ["C:/myproject/file1.rb:31:in `require_relative'",
>   "C:/myproject/file1.rb:31:in`dosome'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:139:in
>   `_perform'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/script/tree/node.rb:50:in`
>   perform'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:384:in
>   `visit_prop'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in`
>   visit'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in
>   `block in visit'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in`
>   block in with_base'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in
>   `with_frame'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in`
>   with_base'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in
>   `visit'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:289:in`
>   block (2 levels) in visit_if'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:289:in
>   `map'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:289:in`
>   block in visit_if'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:179:in
>   `with_environment'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:288:in`
>   visit_if'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in
>   `visit'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in`
>   block in visit'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in
>   `block in with_base'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in`
>   with_frame'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in
>   `with_base'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in`
>   visit'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:491:in
>   `block (2 levels) in visit_directive'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:491:in`
>   map'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:491:in
>   `block in visit_directive'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:179:in`
>   with_environment'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:490:in
>   `visit_directive'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in`
>   visit'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in
>   `block in visit'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in`
>   block in with_base'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in
>   `with_frame'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in`
>   with_base'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in
>   `visit'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:353:in`
>   block (4 levels) in visit_mixin'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:353:in
>   `map'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:353:in`
>   block (3 levels) in visit_mixin'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:179:in
>   `with_environment'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:353:in`
>   block (2 levels) in visit_mixin'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:84:in
>   `perform_arguments'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:348:in`
>   block in visit_mixin'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/stack.rb:98:in
>   `block in with_mixin'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in`
>   with_frame'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/stack.rb:98:in
>   `with_mixin'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:336:in`
>   visit_mixin'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in
>   `visit'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in`
>   block in visit'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in
>   `block in with_base'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in`
>   with_frame'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in
>   `with_base'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in`
>   visit'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:315:in
>   `block (2 levels) in visit_import'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:315:in`
>   map'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:315:in
>   `block in visit_import'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/stack.rb:88:in`
>   block in with_import'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in
>   `with_frame'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/stack.rb:88:in`
>   with_import'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:312:in
>   `visit_import'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in`
>   visit'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in
>   `block in visit'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in`
>   block in with_base'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in
>   `with_frame'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in`
>   with_base'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in
>   `visit'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:315:in`
>   block (2 levels) in visit_import'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:315:in
>   `map'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:315:in`
>   block in visit_import'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/stack.rb:88:in
>   `block in with_import'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in`
>   with_frame'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/stack.rb:88:in
>   `with_import'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:312:in`
>   visit_import'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in
>   `visit'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in`
>   block in visit'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in
>   `block in with_base'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in`
>   with_frame'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in
>   `with_base'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in`
>   visit'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in
>   `block in visit_children'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in`
>   map'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in
>   `visit_children'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:167:in`
>   block in visit_children'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:179:in
>   `with_environment'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:166:in`
>   visit_children'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in
>   `block in visit'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:186:in`
>   visit_root'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in
>   `visit'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:157:in`
>   visit'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:8:in
>   `visit'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in`
>   css_tree'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:29:in
>   `render_with_sourcemap'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/engine.rb:368:in`
>   _render_with_sourcemap'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/engine.rb:285:in
>   `render_with_sourcemap'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:490:in`
>   update_stylesheet'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:215:in
>   `block in update_stylesheets'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:209:in`
>   each'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:209:in
>   `update_stylesheets'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/plugin.rb:82:in`
>   update_stylesheets'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/exec/sass_scss.rb:350:in
>   `watch_or_update'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/exec/sass_scss.rb:50:in`
>   process_result'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/exec/base.rb:52:in
>   `parse'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/lib/sass/exec/base.rb:19:in`
>   parse!'",
>   "C:/tools/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.4.9/bin/scss:13:in
>   `<top (required)>'", "C:/myproject/scss:23:in`load'",
>   "C:/myproject/scss:23:in `'"]

I get this even if `file2.rb` has no text inside and also if I add `# coding: utf-8` as first line of both `file1.rb` and `file2.rb`!

What am I doing wrong? How can I successfully require/import `file2.rb`?

### SASS

As you can see, there is some SASS involved here. I do not know if this is related. The way I execute the script is actually by calling the SASS compiler which will operate on some `.scss` files. In one of my stylesheets I reference the `dosome` function and that is how that function gets called.

Comment: I applied some edits. Original file names were different. I had to extract the most essential logic as original files are very big and it would be pointless to paste them all here

Comment: Can you make a minimal program showing this behaviour, say: A program containing *only* the `require_relative` and nothing else?

Comment: It might be also worth to have a look at file1.rb with a hex editor. Maybe you have some weird character in the code, which just doesn't show up.

Comment: @user1934428: I will give it a try!

Comment: Same issue as before :(

Comment: Hey got it... looks like some character was wrong, there was a strange initial sequence which made the whole thing go bananas as you said. I inspected with an hex editor! Thanks! Post the answer...

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an encoding problem. 
Try to add :

`# encoding: utf-8`

at the beginning of the script.

If this works, you can remove the comment, and set both env variable running :

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Which should add the right tag for the compiler.

But, what version of ruby are you using? Since Ruby 2.0 there is no need to such stuff, as UTF-8 is automatically detected.

Comment: I wrote the version of ruby at the beginning of the question. Also I already wrote that I tried your approach dvxam... :)

Comment: @dvxam: I agree that this should be an encoding issue, but if Ruby really would believe that the string's encoding is US-ASCII, how can it can complain about a "multi-byte" character? There is no such thing in US-ASCII, and I had expected that each byte would simply be interpreted "as is". Of course you would get garbage characters in the output, but I would not expect an error message.

Comment: @user1934428: that error message is worded badly. It basically means that Ruby encountered a character with a value >127, which, if this *were* UTF-8 *would be* part of a multibyte sequence. A better wording would simply be "Invalid character (US-ASCII)" without the "multibyte".